# No Thrift TDebugProtocol?

Tags: java, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm setting up a Thrift server in Java, and I'm trying to set up a TDebugProtocol (mentioned in the Thrift documentation [here](http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thrift-stack.html)), but there doesn't seem to be a `TDebugProtocol.java` file in the `protocol` folder of the [Thrift library](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/protocol).

Does this protocol no longer exist?

Answer (score 2):

Not all things are equally implemented in all parts of the library. Usually this is where the particular contributor stopped. TDebugProtocol is probably just one of the lesser used ones. But given [the C++ version](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TDebugProtocol.cpp) it should not be so hard to build a Java version from it.